# How to use the Angular @HostListener onLoad to get the current width of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I'm currently using the Angular [@HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to get the current width of the viewport `onResize()` like this:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event?) {
    window.innerWidth <= 400 ? this.width = 200 : this.width = 400;
  }
```

But I also need a way to set this.width `onLoad()` of the component (in the constructor or at least in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle).

I didn't found a way to do this with the HostListener. Is there a good alternative to get the current width of the viewport (on resize and on load) and react to it?

My goal is the set the maxWidth of a [Leaflet-PopUp](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup) on mobile viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are using bootstrap you can use bootstrap CSS media queries,

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

If otherwise what you have tried is right way without using external dependencies.

Comment: I need a way to do it with Angular, because the leaflet library is generating it's own CSS based on properties like: L.popup({ maxWidth: 600, maxHeight: 500 }, marker).. I also want to avoid the use of !important in my CSS files..

Answer (score 0):

simplay you can just call the method it selft as you dont use the event object so

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.width);
    this.onResize();
    console.log(this.width);
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjtx7a)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in constructor you can inject `DOCUMENT` built-in token to get `document`. It has `defaultView` property which is current `window` or `null`. If it's not `null` you can get its width:

```js
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) {defaultView}: Document) {
  this.width = defaultView ? defaultView.innerWidth : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...

clientWidth: number;

constructor(){
   this.initMethod();
}

initMethod() {
    this.clientWidth = (document.childNodes[1] as any).clientWidth;
}
```

Its another method instead of accessing through a sepperate @Viewchild or a @HostListener to get the current width